# ListView Contacts List breaking main activity

Tags: android

I am trying to make the Contact tab in my app to list the users address book's name and phone number, however when I set the adapter for contactlist the app no longer shows its tabs and the fragment is empty.

Code:

```
package com.spgrn.smsim;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Locale;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

    /**
     * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
     * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
     * {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which will keep every
     * loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory intensive, it
     * may be best to switch to a
     * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
     */
    SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

    /**
     * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
     */
    ViewPager mViewPager;
    String phoneNumber;
    ListView contactlist;
    ArrayList <String> aa= new ArrayList<String>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        contactlist= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.contactv);

        getNumber(this.getContentResolver()); 
        // Set up the action bar.
        final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the activity.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        // When swiping between different sections, select the corresponding
        // tab. We can also use ActionBar.Tab#select() to do this if we have
        // a reference to the Tab.
        mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }
        });

        // For each of the sections in the app, add a tab to the action bar.
        for (int i = 0; i < mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
            // Create a tab with text corresponding to the page title defined by
            // the adapter. Also specify this Activity object, which implements
            // the TabListener interface, as the callback (listener) for when
            // this tab is selected.
            Log.v("I", "curtab="+ mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount() + "i=" + i);
            if (i != 1)
                actionBar.addTab(
                        actionBar.newTab()
                        .setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                        .setTabListener(this),
                        false);
            if (i == 1)
                actionBar.addTab(
                        actionBar.newTab()
                        .setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                        .setTabListener(this),
                        true);
        }
    }

    public void getNumber(ContentResolver cr)
    {
        Cursor phones = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,null,null, null);
        while (phones.moveToNext())
        {
          String name=phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
          phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
          System.out.println(name + phoneNumber); 
          aa.add(name + "\n" + phoneNumber);
        }
        Log.v("Contacts", "Total= " + phones.getCount());
        phones.close();// close cursor
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,aa);
            contactlist.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        if (id == R.id.action_compose) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, NewMessage.class);
            this.startActivity(intent);
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
        // When the given tab is selected, switch to the corresponding page in
        // the ViewPager.
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    }

    /**
     * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
     * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
     */
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
            // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
            //return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
            switch (position){
            case 0:
                Fragment fragmentContacts = new FragmentContacts();
                return fragmentContacts;
            case 1:
                Fragment fragmentMessages = new FragmentMessages();
                return fragmentMessages;
            case 2:
                Fragment fragmentAccounts = new FragmentAccounts();
                return fragmentAccounts;
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 5 total pages.
            return 3;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase(l);
                case 1:
                    return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);
                case 2:
                    return getString(R.string.title_section3).toUpperCase(l);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    //Make fragments for each tab
    public static class FragmentContacts extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        public FragmentContacts() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_contacts,
                    container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }
    public static class FragmentMessages extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        public FragmentMessages() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main,
                    container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }
    public static class FragmentAccounts extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        public FragmentAccounts() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_accounts,
                    container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }
//End of Tab Fragments
    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        /**
         * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
         * number.
         */
        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

Also, in the debugger I noticed the main activity was suspended due to a run time exception. Here is the stack:

```
Thread [<1> main] (Suspended (exception RuntimeException))  
    <VM does not provide monitor information>   
    ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 2195    
    ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 2245 
    ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread, ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 135    
    ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(Message) line: 1196  
    ActivityThread$H(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 102    
    Looper.loop() line: 136 
    ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 5017    
    Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not available [native method]  
    Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 515  
    ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 779  
    ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 595 
    XposedBridge.main(String[]) line: 126   
    NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method]
```

Thanks!

Edit: Looking more, I think the list needs to be generated in the fragments class, but I am not sure what to do with the context. I keep getting a NullPointerException.
Code:

```
public static class FragmentContacts extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        public FragmentContacts() {
        }
        Context context;
        String phoneNumber;
        ListView contactlist;
        ArrayList <String> aa= new ArrayList<String>();
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_contacts,
                    container, false);
            contactlist = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.contactv);
            getNumber(context.getContentResolver());
            return rootView;
        }
        public void getNumber(ContentResolver cr)
        {
            Cursor phones = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,null,null, null);
            while (phones.moveToNext())
            {
              String name=phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
              phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
              System.out.println(name + phoneNumber); 
              aa.add(name + "\n" + phoneNumber);
            }
            Log.v("Contacts", "Total= " + phones.getCount());
            phones.close();// close cursor
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity()
                    .getApplicationContext(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,aa);
                contactlist.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

write

```
context=container.getContext();
```

in `onCreateView`

```
   @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_contacts,
                container, false);
        contactlist = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.contactv);
         context=container.getContext();
       getNumber(context.getContentResolver());
        return rootView;
    }
```

Comment: That solved my issue, thanks! Can you explain how that fixes it?

Comment: Activity extends context so using "this" can can access it in Activity. But in case of fragment you get an activity reference in onActivityCreated and to get context in onCreateView you can use the context of container that this fragment lies in.